# How to set-up custom domain name in Azure Container Instance?

Tags: dns, static, containers, ip, azure-container-instances

I am trying to assign a custom DNS for my container instances.

What are the solutions to create a custom DNS? Actually I am looking to run my container instance with a static IP address and trying to find a solution that's is cheaper than Application gateway and Azure firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Created container instances with static Ip address like below:

[image]

As for as I know, there is no way to directly set the custom domain for ACI, create a CNAME record in the DNS zone that points to the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of your container instance. For example, if your container instance has FQDN of `mycontainerinstance.eastus.azurecontainer.io` create a `CNAME` record in your DNS provider to redirect your subdomain like `www.mydomain.com` that points to `mycontainerinstance.eastus.azurecontainer.io`.If so, you can access your ACI via subdomain `www.example.com`.

Ensure that in DNS zone enter a name that corresponds to your custom domain name.

[image]

***References***:

[Tutorial: Create custom Azure DNS records for a web app | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-web-sites-custom-domain)

[Custom domain names and certificates in Azure Container Apps | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/custom-domains-certificates)